# When are one line multiple conversions not allowed in QT, like QString to char*

Tags: c++, qt, char, qstring

So recently I was converting (trying to) from **QString** to **char*** using:

```
QString str;

const char *ptr = str.toLatin1().constData();
```

Which did not throw any error, but my program was not working and I spent a lot of time figuring out what the error was:
According to 
https://wiki.qt.io/Technical_FAQ#How_can_I_convert_a_QString_to_char.2A_and_vice_versa.3F

> Note that it is necessary to store the bytearray before you call
>   data() on it, a call like the following.

```
const char *c_str2 = str2.toLocal8Bit().data();
```

> will make the application crash as the
>   QByteArray has not been stored and hence no longer exists

So my question is how does one know when this type of single line conversions are dangerous and is better to avoid them. In general when the result is a pointer or is this just a particular case? What other similar examples have you came across?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Note that the chained conversions are not wrong.  The lines you show will not crash anything.  On the other hand, they aren't useful, because they have no side effect and the variable they create is already dangling.  But `puts(str.toLatin1().constData());` is just fine because you use the pointer before the temporary objects get cleaned up.

Comment: So I tested using the chain conversion directly into the function calling and it is indeed working: `function1(str.toLatin1().constData()); ` where function1 receives the pointer as parameter `void fuction1(const char *ptr){...`. Could you elaborate more why in this case the temp object is not cleaned?

Comment: As Yakk mentioned, the temporary object is cleaned up *at the end of the full-expression*, which means after the call to `puts()` has returned.  When you use an expression as a statement, the entire statement (everything between `;` statement terminators) is a single full-expression.

Answer (score 3):

In C++ you the programmer are responsible to manage lifetime of objects and data.

Sometimes this is hidden for you, where other objects manage the lifetime.

In this case it is not.

```
const char *c_str2 = str2.toLocal8Bit().data();
```

ths `QString` doesn't have a `Local8Bit` version of itself stored within it.  When you call `toLocal8Bit` it creates a new object in automatic/temporary storage with a different encoding.

When this `Local8Bit` object is destroyed, it takes its data with it.

On this case you created a temporary object.  Its lifetime ends at the end of the full expression you created it.

The `.data()` member returns a pointer *into* the object you call it on.  This pointer represents a non-owning view of the data.  When the object you have a pointer into ends its lifetime, this pointer is no longer valid.

So `c_str2` is a valid pointer until the `;` at which point the pointer is dangling.

Whenever you work with non-smart pointers in C++ you must understand the lifetime of the data pointed to.  If you don't, your code will at best work by accident.